# AngularFire – Nested Firebase requests don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've got the following code in a controller:

```
FirebaseService.$child('tasks').$on('loaded', function(tasks) {
    console.log('tasks loaded');
    FirebaseService.$child('taskTemplates').$on('loaded', function(taskTemplates) {
        console.log('taskTemplates loaded');
    });
});
```

The console only shows `tasks loaded` and the second console.log is never executed. If I request those children sequential (the request for `taskTemplates` is not in the loaded-callback) it works seamlessly. Is there a reason for this strange behaviour?

Some background information: When the tasks are loaded, I need to do check something with them and in some case – and only then – I want to load the taskTemplates.

Here's my FirebaseService, if that's helpful:

```
app
.value('FIREBASE_URL', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseIO.com/')
.service('FirebaseService', function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {
    return $firebase(new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL));
});
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Why bother with a nested call to loaded? When the parent data loads, it already contains all the children, thus the child has already loaded.

Comment: Well `tasks` is a sibling of `taskTemplates` – does that still apply then?

Comment: I misunderstood, thinking that you calling $child on the `tasks` object. Question withdrawn!

Answer (score 0):

My first suspicion was that this error looks similar to [this series of bugs](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/262), one of which is that loaded only triggered once if declared after initial load. Since FirebaseService calls $firebase on the parent path, all the child data is already cached locally, which would cause the `loaded` event to be fired synchronously (maybe before you've attached your listener and thus triggering the bug listed above).

However, I was unable to reproduce the behavior you've shown above in angularFire versions 0.6.0, 0.7.0, or the latest master branch. Here's my repro:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.6/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="log in logs">{{log}}</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app', ['firebase']).controller('ctrl', function($firebase, $scope) {
        $scope.logs = [];
        var fb = new Firebase('https://kato-sandbox.firebaseio-demo.com/');
        var ref = new $firebase(fb);
        var childA = ref.$child('alpha');
        childA.$on('loaded', function() {
            $scope.logs.push('alpha loaded');
            var childB = ref.$child('bravo');
            childB.$on('loaded', function() {
                $scope.logs.push('bravo loaded');
            })
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully that will help you narrow the scope of the error, although it's not in itself a resolution.